# Switching java stream to cipher stream

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, objectinputstream

I'm trying to create a protocol that let's the client send the server it's login name. After this the server get's the clients password from the server and creates a cipherkey from that. The client creates a key from the password that is entered. This way I'm trying to get a secure connection.

However, after sending the username, getting the password etc. I'm trying to create a new objectinputstream from the cypherstream to read the data, but it blocks. I can't find a way to get it working, even after looking at a lot of other similar questions.

**Serverside**

```
private void switchToChipherStreams(String username) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {
    byte key[] = dbMediator.getPasswordCypher(username);
    SecretKey key64 = new SecretKeySpec(key, "Blowfish");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key64);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(new CipherOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), cipher));
    out.reset();
    out.flush();
    out.writeObject("switch");
    in = new ObjectInputStream(new CipherInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), cipher));
}
```

**Client side**

```
private void switchToChipherStreams(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {
    //Generate key
    byte[] key = new byte[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (password.length() > i) {
            key[i] = password.getBytes()[i];
        } else {
            key[i] = (byte) i;
        }
    }
    //Setup cipher streams
    SecretKey key64 = new SecretKeySpec(key, "Blowfish");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key64);
    in = new ObjectInputStream(new CipherInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), cipher));
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(new CipherOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), cipher));
    out.reset();
    out.flush();
    out.writeObject("switch");
}
```

At the moment it's trowing an exception (invalid header), because I'm trying to send data over, but if I don't it just blocks.

Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here, or if it's is even possible changing to ciphered objectinputstream.

Kind regards,

Jur

***EDIT***

Changed the cipher to encrypt and decrypt of in and output streams, new code:

**Serverside**

```
byte key[] = dbMediator.getPasswordCypher(username);
    SecretKey key64 = new SecretKeySpec(key, "Blowfish");
    Cipher cipheren = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
    cipheren.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key64);
    Cipher cipherde = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
    cipheren.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key64);
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(new CipherOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), cipheren));
    out.reset();
    out.flush();
    out.writeObject("switch");
    in = new ObjectInputStream(new CipherInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), cipherde));
```

**Client side**

```
//Generate key
        byte[] key = new byte[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (password.length() > i) {
                key[i] = password.getBytes()[i];
            } else {
                key[i] = (byte) i;
            }
        }
        //Setup cipher streams
        SecretKey key64 = new SecretKeySpec(key, "Blowfish");
        Cipher cipheren = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipheren.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key64);
        Cipher cipherde = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipheren.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key64);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new CipherOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), cipheren));
        out.reset();
        out.flush();
        out.writeObject("switch");
        in = new ObjectInputStream(new CipherInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), cipherde));
```

Now the invalid head problem is solved, but is freezes both client and server when objectinputstream constructor is called.

Comment: Don't you have to close the stream at some point?

Comment: Closing the stream results in closing the socket

Comment: What about creating a new Thread for each Client Request on the Server Side?

Comment: For each client connecting to the server I'm creating a new thread. The user sends it's username, server gets the password from the DB and creates a key from the password, as does the client. If the client entered the wrong password, the stream would fail.
However, I do have to make the switch. But it just freezes when creating a new objectinputstream when I don't immediatly send something to it. When I do send something I get an invalid head exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a cipher input *and* output stream from the same Cipher object. You need two Cipher objects, one in DECRYPT mode and one in ENCRYPT mode.

Create and flush the `ObjectOutputStream`before the `ObjectInputStream` at both ends.

Comment: I changed the ciphers and created the objectoutputstream on both sides then creating a objectinputstream, but it still freezes on calling the constructor of the objectinputstream

Comment: There are ciphers where the same algorithm is used for encryption and decryption.

Comment: @zaph Of course there are. I haven't stated otherwise. 99.999% of stream ciphers would fall into that category. The point is about `Cipher` *objects*, which can't be in two modes at the same time.

Comment: @JurClerkx Try flushing the `ObjectOutputStream` before creating the `ObjectInputStream`. Possibly the underlying `CipherOutputStream` needs flushing.